# LiveData only triggered on orientation change

Tags: android, textview, viewmodel, android-mvvm

I have a `MutableLiveData` variable `displayText`, which is the text for a `TextView`, set through data binding

The code:

```java
vm.displayTextValue.value = "New Value"//code for updating
```

```java
binding.setViewModel(/* ViewModel variable*/)//set data variable in the Fragment
```

```xml
<layout>
<data>
<variable
name="viewModel"
type="com.myapp.theViewModel"/>

<TextView
    android:text="@{viewModel.displayTextValue}" />
</layout>
```

Somehow, the text of the `TextView` only changes on orientation change, but does not change when the variable is changed. Why?

Comment: You must call the setValue method to update value from main thread. If the code is executed in a worker thread, you can use the postValue method instead to update the LiveData.

Comment: It is called from the main thread. And I set the method to `setValue()`. The result is still the same.

Comment: ok, you use notifyPropertyChanged after change value in code?

Comment: @LCZ `but does not change when the variable is changed` where do you call this change method, can you show some code?

Comment: Ok, the variable is changed on button press in the fragment.`button.setOnClickListener{vm.displayText.value = "New Value"}`

Comment: Have you set lifecycleowner properly? Please show us the part where you instantiate binding, attaching viewmodel and lifecycleowner, etc. Also, do you ever re-assign another livedata to `displayTextValue`